# Session doesn't start (Symfony 2.7.1, Apache 2.2)

Tags: php, apache, symfony, session

So as title suggests, session doesn't start after submitting a form. `$_SESSION` is null after submitting. There are no errors, and redirect is to the page after successful login. I am pretty sure that is no related to any configuration problem in symfony, simply because I have exact copy on my local machine, and everything works fine.

That's why I think it's related with Apache 2.2. auto-session is off in `php.ini`. Any suggestions?

Comment: One additional thing. I have another project on this server, and it's on Drupal. Session is created properly on this one. So maybe there are some specific things related with Apache 2.2 - Symfony2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all of that was because of Varnish. I didn't have Varnish for that project, at least I thought so, because I had configuration done wrong, and Varnish was working for both projects (that which I wanted, and which I don't). So I think the problems was with cached form (generally page). I think all of that, because recently I switched off Varnish, and everything working like it should.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Session Management of Symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

> As stated elsewhere, Symfony Sessions are designed to replace the use of PHP's native session_*() functions and use of the $_SESSION superglobal. Additionally, it is mandatory for Symfony to start the session.

(http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html)

Comment: Good point for checking session, but still doesn't matter, because if you checking your user using toolbar on app_dev.php, it's not set.